# How register OCX library on Win7 Prof x64 EN

Tags: c#, windows-7, gis, ocx

I have a problem with my MapWinGIS.ocx file on Windows 7.

I try to register this control in two ways:

1. Using regsvr32 (from system32 directory and from SysWOW64 directory), but I get error message like below

> The module "C:\MapWinGIS.ocx" failed
>   to load.
>
> Make sure the binary is stored at the
>   specified path or debug it to check
>   for problems with the binary or
>   dependent .DLL files.
>
> The specified module could not be
>   found.

I use command console by clicking right mouse button and choosing "Run As Administrator".

1. I downloaded and installed OCX/DLL Manager. I can't register MapWinGIS.ocx file by using this application.

I don't know why. It is strange because in my work on other Windows 7 version I installed it properly.

I think that there are some problems with local policy on my system.

What do you think about this? What can be wrong?

Regards
Adam

Answer (score 2):

The activex control might have other dependencies which are not present (DLLs, most likely). You can check them with Dependency walker.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I downloaded Dependency walker and Dependency Viewer. Nice applications.

Comment: I check dependencies on Win7 x64 and Win XP x86 and I can register this .ocx file on Win Xp, but I have problem with register it on Win7. I used Dependency Walker on both systems and there are some missing library dll files but on Win XP is can register this .ocx file. What is wrong?

Comment: I had this experience with something else and my solution was hunting the files down and putting them next to the ocx.

Comment: You cannot determine COM dependencies with Dependency Walker. You can observe the failure to load in Process Monitor and often that will turn up enough information to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

install MSVBVM50

http://soft.softoogle.com/ap/msvbvm50-dll-get-113.shtml

click to download the file